# Toggle between 2 pages in same tab in an ionic 3 app based on login data

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

i have 2 profile pages and one tab ( **profile tab** )
i want to change between them based on the user who logged in ( if student or tutor ) , in an **ionic 3** app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make us of `*ngIf`

> Conditionally includes a template based on the value of an expression

```
value = // either tutor or student depending on what you get from services 

<div *ngIf = "value == 'tutor'">
 //display tutor template
</div>
```

---

```
<div *ngIf = "value == 'student'">
 //display student template
</div>
```

Comment: by setting key value in Storage when user logged in and check for it everytime he entered this tab right ?